# How to emulate BACnet communication protocol on raspberry pi stacks

Tags: raspberry-pi, switch-statement, bacnet

I am currently working on my senior design project. I have made the stack of raspberry pi's. I am just wondering on how to create a BACnet stack where each raspberry pi device is a unique device, with a unique device ID. Additionally, we plan to use a cisco switch to connect with other raspberry pi stacks. I understand that there is a bacpypes module, which is amazing but it is mainly for dealing with a bacnet device. In my scenario, I need to create a stack of raspberry pi's emulating the BACnet communication protocol. 
It would be really helpful

Answer (score 1):

Quickest way:

1. Compile Steve Karg's BACnet stack by following this: "[How to build a FOSS BACnet Server based on Steve Karg’s SourceForge project](http:////https://www.bac-test.com/how-to-build-a-foss-bacnet-server-based-on-steve-kargs-sourceforge-project/)" on the BITS blog.
2. Run the BACnet SErver sample executable on each of your Pis:

   cd /demo/server
   ./bacserv

Comment: Link not working:
http://https//www.bac-test.com/how-to-build-a-foss-bacnet-server-based-on-steve-kargs-sourceforge-project/

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest trying BAC0, a python implementation of BACnet.
BAC0 is a high level wrapper around bacpypes. And when launched, becomes a BACnet device on any network.

https://github.com/ChristianTremblay/BAC0

https://bac0.readthedocs.io/en/latest/